# Handle table data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to collect data and represent it as given below, but not sure what data type to use, in case of c an multi dimension array will do the job.

```
                   Box 1  Box 2   Box 3     
Red                 5       8       3
Yellow              3       7       2 
Blue                5       4       9
```

The number of box and the colours are not predefined. I create this by reading file box1, box2 .....

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Do you want a data structure to represent a table with markup in the cells? How do you derive the markup from the data?

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dictionary` {`color` : `list of box count`}.

e.g.

```
>>> colors = {}
>>> colors["red"] = [1,2,3] #you can dynamically add to list while reading files.
>>> colors["yellow"] = [0,2,4]
>>> colors 
{'yellow': [0, 2, 4], 'red': [1, 2, 3]}
```

then you can iterate over the dictionary and print data as you want.

Comment: It good solution if order of colours  is not important. Instead need other solution.

Comment: Good solution but, the number of object in each file are not aware till i pars through the file. so i can not get do "colors["yellow"] = [0,2,4]" only after reading all files i get this information.   I want to save the information just after parsing the each file.

Answer (score 2):

@Heisenberg suggest solution with unsorted dict. But if need order of added items you can use next solution:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Colors(OrderedDict):
    """Store colors in depend from added order"""
    def __setitem__(self, color, value):
        if color in self:
            del self[color]
        OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, color, value)
colors_table = Colors()
colors_table["red"] = [1,2,3]
colors_table["yellow"] = [0,2,4]
colors_table["blue"] = [2,3,4]
print colors_table # print Colors([('red', [1, 2, 3]), ('yellow', [0, 2, 4]), ('blue', [2, 3, 4])])
```

Comment: The problem is that i do not have full information at once, I need to read the data from different files box1.txt, box2.txt & box3.txt. When i read the first file i create the dict and create the entire inforamtion, when i read second file how can i update this information ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-dimensional array in python as well, but in a slightly different manner. Here it will be an array of arrays. So your data structure will look something like:

```
matrix = [
    ['Color', 'Box1', 'Box2', 'Box3'],
    ['Red', 5, 8, 3],
    ['Yellow', 3, 7, 2],
    ['Blue', 5, 4, 9]
]
```